# creating 3D image of png files with transparent background using surf

Tags: matlab, 3d, background, png, transparent

Problem : The image loses its transparency when plot using surf

I have already figured out how to create a png file with a transparent background as described in numerous other threads.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213320/make-a-pixel-transparent-in-matlab)

However, when plot using surf.m, the image is not transparent

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
img = imread('image.png');

A1 = ones(size(img));A2 = ones(size(img));A3 = ones(size(img));
A1(img(:,:,1)==0)=0;A2(img(:,:,2)==0)=0;A3(img(:,:,3)==0)=0;

A = A1+A2+A3;
A= A(:,:,1);

imwrite(img,'test.png','alpha',A);
[img,map,alpha] = imread('test.png');

ximage = [-.5,.5;-.5,.5];
yimage = [0,0;0,0];
zimage = [.5,.5;-.5,-.5];

surf(ximage,yimage,zimage,'Cdata',img,'Facecolor','texturemap','Edgecolor','none','alphadata',alpha);
axis vis3d
```

The code converts image.png (blue square) to a test.png with a transparent background (get rid of the black background). test.png is then used to generate a surf plot which turns out to be not transparent. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image: blue square with black background - need to plot this as a 3D slice without the black background]

Comment: Please indent code lines four space for nice formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function called `alpha` in MATLAB which sets transparency for the objects in current axes. I suggest to change the variable named `alpha` to another name by replacing the following line

```
[img,map,alpha] = imread('test.png');
```

to

```
[img,map,alphaChannel] = imread('test.png');
```

Now, after running `surf`, you can set the transparency for your plot through `alpha` function.

**Using `alpha` function**

```
surf(ximage,yimage,zimage,'Cdata',img,'Facecolor','texturemap','Edgecolor', ...
                          'none','alphadata',alpha);
alpha(0.5); %# line added
axis vis3d
```

**Using `surf` function**

If you want to set the transparency through the `surf` function, you need to add `'FaceAlpha'` parameter:

```
surf(ximage,yimage,zimage,'Cdata',img,'Facecolor','texturemap','Edgecolor', ... 
                          'none','AlphaData',alphaChannel,'FaceAlpha',0.5);
```

**Result**

[image: Image obtained through through any example above]

More information about [`alpha`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/alpha.html) and [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html#FaceAlpha) functions.

---

### Setting a matrix transparency

But those functions above sets the transparency for the entire plot. If you want to set your original matrix of transparency, you need to pass `'FaceAlpha','texture'` parameter to `surf`:

```
handler = surf( ximage , yimage , zimage , 'Cdata', img , ...
    'FaceColor','texturemap',                             ...
    'EdgeColor','none',                                   ... 
    'FaceAlpha','texture',                                ...
    'AlphaData', alphaChannel);
axis vis3d
```

**Result**

[image: Image obtained by setting 'FaceAlpha']

[More details](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f3-5927.html). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response Victor Hugo. However, the result I want is such that the transparency is set to 0 in the black border and 1 everywhere else (blue box). Alpha and/or Facealpha set the transparency of the entire matrix to the same value. I want to somehow tell surf to use the alpha matrix and not just a scalar value. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So I am trying to use this technique for placing an image on an actual surface plot with elevation data similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719502/how-can-i-plot-an-image-jpg-in-matlab-in-both-2-d-and-3-d  How do I prevent the elevation data from being affected?

Comment: @user1854628 what is the "elevation data" in the example you sent me? Is it the sphere around the image?